# Сократить код Jquery

Tags: jquery, инспекция-кода

Можно ли как то сократить данный код ? Не очень силён в jquery
Спасибо

```
$('.category-header .list-group').clone().appendTo('.mobile-menu').hide();
$('#cart').clone().appendTo('.mobile-menu');
$('.mobile-menu').append('<div class="mobile-background">');
$(".toggle-mnu").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $(".mobile-menu .list-group, .mobile-background").stop().slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: что делает этот код? Он работает верно?

Comment: Работает, есть меню в $('.category-header .list-group'), клонирует его и вставляет в '.mobile-menu' и скрывает его. После #cart так же вставляет в мобильное меню.
После по нажатию на кнопку открывает данное меню и добавляет класс "on"